# OpenCV on rpi - segmentation fault in System.loadLibrary

Tags: java, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install OpenCV on a raspberry pi and, after many tries configuring cmake, have succeeded in producing opencv-400.jar and libopencv_java400.so The various guides on the web do not say what to do next.

I have the jar in my class path, the test code compiles fine, and printing out `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` includes the directory containing the .so file.  In a different directory, /usr/local/lib, the make process has put a stack of .a files.  The cmake instructions said by making the libraries non shared the required parts would all be put in the java .so file.  I am not sure this makes sense?  I also had to specify /usr/local as the build prefix - perhaps that should be something else on a pi?

> The line System.loadLibrary("opencv_java400") produces an unadorned Segmentation fault.

... which it shouldn't of course.  If anyone is connecting the rpi camera to opencv and accessing that from java, perhaps you could share the cmake parameters.

Comment: Started the cmake process again with many different combinations of -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF v.s.  -U BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to "unset" the parameter, and combinations of spaces/no spaces, upper/lower case and still get the line in the cmake output on the screen saying "Link libraries: Dynamic load"  So it looks to me as if I have failed to get the required libraries in my libopencv_java400.so file.

Comment: turns out opencv won't run on raspberry pi under java unless you recompile ffmpeg: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10157 the work arround is to not use ffmpeg to access the camera.... more to follow...

Comment: Nope, having ffmpeg in or out makes no difference. I cannot sort it my self, and there is no help here, on the opencv forums, the rpi forums.  I am giving up.

Answer (score 0):

After reverting to opencv 3.3.0 so I did not need to figure out cmake, I got opencv working on the pi with c++.  I then wrapped my required opencv commands in JNI... and still got segmenation fault.  I then learnt to use gdb and traced the error, very quickly, to libopenmpt.  A quick search said this causes a segmentation fault when out of memory.

The solution in this case is to run `java -Xss128m ...` to run my code.

This, I am guessing, is a fix for using opencv 4 from the built java components.