# can I use cmake/make to compile all and only the cpp/hpp files I used?

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

One of many nice features of java is that if I type `javac x.java`, it will compile the classes in `x.java` and any other classes mentioned in `x`, and recursively look for other required classes.  I can then find the `.class` files, put them in a jar and I have a minimal executable for x. How would I do the same for c++? I expect I need to do it with cmake, but "minimal" does not seem to be in the modern vocabulary.

I am trying to get opencv4 running on a raspberry pi - lots of guides on the web; primarily targeting python and the rest don't work in my experience. OpenCV is classic bloatware and the solution is to automate the build process rather than simplify it.

I feel I ought to be able to start with a relevant example application and run, for example:
`g++ facedetect.cpp`
then (manually) compile the missing bits.

There are however missing `.hpp` files that are constructed by the cmake/make process and the only option seems to be to build the entire edifice first.

Comment: It seems there is just one file cmake generates: `opencv_modules.hpp` that is a list of headers for the things I have installed using apt-get install on my raspberry pi.  What I'd like is to run cmake on my target application and either generate that file or generate a list of things I need to apt-get install in order to run it.  I am sure its a flag...

Comment: there is no direct equivalent in C++, the closest equivalent would be to link statically as much as possible and then strip all the dead symbols when compiling either an executable or provide a list of symbols that you want exported

Comment: Thanks PeterT, that is what I suspected, but hoped would not be the case.  Bloatware is the way the future obviously.  The solution is to wait until someone associated with the OpenCV4 CMake Project decide to write a step by step script for java or for c++ on the pi.

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of bloat. As I said, you can strip symbols to only things even to the degree of stripping class member function if they're not used. It's just usually only done with static libraries and you can link opencv statically just fine. You just can't call static library functions with JNI

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV4 is a CMake based project. No need to combine the classes and source files etc, that is what CMake is doing for you! You can just use this [guide](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/) which has every step written out for you.

Comment: Following this guide, i cannot get opencv 4.0.0 running on a clean install of raspbian stretch using a 16Gig card (pi 3).  No idea why and the step by step approach does not help debug.  Worse, I want to use C++ or java interfaces, both of these are broken for 4.0.0 - references to follow.

Comment: java and opencv segmentation fault: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239782/opencv-on-rpi-segmentation-fault-in-system-loadlibrary and opencv 4 does not produce pkgconfig file https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13154